# Send Array of images to new view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I currently have a Tableview that when the user clicks, will send them to a new viewcontroller that will display one picture. However, because I need them to be able to swipe to display a second picture associated with the first (depending on which row selected), I am trying to create an array to be sent. I (think?) have successfully created an array, but I'm running into problems with the code as it will not "send" correctly. I am wondering where I am wrong, and what changes I need to make to be able to send the array, so the user can swipe and see the second picture. If you need more code, please let me know and I will edit it with it in there. Thank you!

```
let firstchoice: [UIImage] = [
    UIImage(named: "Appa1")!,
    UIImage(named: "Appa2")!
    ]


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    ///Right way here
    ///You can easily manage using this
    let Vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "imageViewController") as! imageViewController



    ///Here you have written four Animal names in Array
    ///So There is going to four case 0,1,2,3 and a default case
    switch indexPath.row
    {
    case 0:
        Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: firstchoice)
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        break;
    case 1:
        Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "AppA2")!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        break;
    case 2:
        Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "AppB")!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        break;
    case 3:
        Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "AppC")!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        break;
    case 4:
        Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "AppD")!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        break;
    case 5:
        Vc.passedImage = UIImage.init(named: "AppE")!
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        break;
```

Image View Controller:

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds


class imageViewController: UIViewController,GADBannerViewDelegate, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var bannerView: GADBannerView!

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var myImageView: UIImageView!


    //var passedImage : UIImage! = nil
    var passedImage : [UIImage]


    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myImageView.image = passedImage
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false

        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5.0
```

Comment: Your `passedImage` seems to be a `UIImage` variable in `imageViewController`. What you need to do is change that to `[UIImage]`. This will let you store an array of images.

Comment: Makes no sense. You create an array but you never do anything with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `passedImage` seems to be a `UIImage` variable in `imageViewController`. What you need to do is change that to `[UIImage]`. This will let you store an array of images.

After which you `switch` would look like this.

```
switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
        Vc.passedImage = firstchoice
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        break;
    case 1:
        Vc.passedImage = [UIImage.init(named: "AppA2")!]
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Vc, animated: true)
        break;
    case 2:
    // Rest of your cases follow suit.
}
```

You would need to access an image from the image array using their respective index.

Sidenote: Use *lowerCamelCase* for variable names like they say in the [Swift naming conventions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming).

Comment: Literally was typing out that's what I did and it worked. Thank you! My viewcontroller says " var passedimage : [UIImage] ". Is that correct?  Also, Will I need to use UIpageviewcontrol to display all of them?

Comment: @beans217 you might want to rename the variable name to `passedImages` ;) How to display it is upto you.

Comment: ha, good point. but is that the correct way to correct what you had originally stated?

Comment: @beans217 yes and if your switch statement looks like what i wrote, then yea you are good to go :)

Comment: That works, but one more problem has arisen in the view controller. =\ I have " self.myImageView.image = passedImage" that displays "Cannot assign value of type '[UIImage]' to type 'UIImage?'"  Is this because I am using a UIImage and need to use a UIPageViewControl? I edited original question

Comment: @beans217 like i have said in my answer in my last line. If you need an image from the array, you need to access it with the respective index. For getting the first image you can do passedImages.first. You can only add one image to an image view. To display multiple images you need multiple image views.

Comment: Starting to see how it should work. Will I need to have code in the imageviewcontroller that says when they swipe, display second..third..etc picture?

Comment: @beans217 your questions have deviated from the original question which i answered. You should probably post another question if you have a lot to ask. And like i said earlier, how to display it is entirely upto you. I've shown you how to get the image array to next view controller like your question asks :)

Comment: Will do, Thank you!